# How to pass an Output filename as a parameter to the next transformation in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

An output file is created at run time and that filename has to be passed down as a parameter to the next transformation for further use.

Comment: Have you looked at `Get files from result`? Once the output file is created it should be in the job's file results list.

Comment: Yes Brian, I have connected my output file to the 'GET FILES FROM RESULT' step.                                                                                         The order is like                                                                    (TRANSFORMATION1) outputfile->get files from result->copy rows to result                                                                                       (TRANSFORMATION2) Get rows from result->set variables->execute SQL to load filename into table

Comment: This is not not passing any filename into the table

Comment: You're using `Copy rows to result`. That's for DB result sets. There is a separate result area in every job for files. Every file that is touched by any step should be recorded in the file results. Try the `Get files from result` step not the `Get rows from result`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian.D.Myers It worked perfect!